# Obtain unique connections from one column to another in dataframe

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have a dataset

```
|c1| c2|
 a   c
 a   b
 a   b
 c   d
 c   a
```

I want to obtain a frequency column such that I can identify number of unique connections from c2 to c1
i.e the results should look something like the following.

```
|c1| c2| freq|
 a   c    2
 a   b    2
 a   b    2
 c   d    2
 c   a    2
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Is it `r` or `Pandas` DataFrame?

Comment: d.b - 4th value should be 2 since c has 2 unique connections coming from c2.
MaxU - Either of them will work, have the dataframe both in R and Pandas.

Comment: Not sure why I got a negative vote for this question. Whoever voted, if you specify why you downvoted, it will help me next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`: `dplyr`

```
df%>%group_by(c1)%>%dplyr::mutate(freq=length(unique(c2)))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   c1 [2]
     c1    c2  freq
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1     a     c     2
2     a     b     2
3     a     b     2
4     c     d     2
5     c     a     2
```

In `python`:`pandas`

```
df['freq']=df.groupby(['c1'])['c2'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique())

df

Out[49]: 
  c1 c2 freq
0  a  c    2
1  a  b    2
2  a  b    2
3  c  d    2
4  c  a    2
```

Comment: Thanks Wen. This was helpful

Comment: @Wen - I did upvote, wasn't aware of accepting an answer. I have accepted it now. Thanks

Comment: @Sneha, Have a nice day ~ BTW : It is how SO works as per MaxU